# Get unmatched items from first list when comparing two large lists of pocos

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have two lists of objects which have a common property called OrderNumber.

The first list has about 20000 items and the second list has about 1.5 million items.

I need an efficient way of finding items from list 1 which dont have a match in list 2. I am currently using Linq and it takes more than 20 mins to compute the solution. I am not able to find an efficient solution to this online.

My code so far

```
notmatched.AddRange(List1.Where(l1=> !list2.Select(l2=> l2.OrderNumber).Contains(l1.OrderNumber)).Select(l1 => new SomeObj 
{
OrderNumber = l1.OrderNumber
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the built in Except extension provided by Linq is fast enough providing a custom IEqualityComparer. My implementation may not work for your use-case but given 1.5 million Poco classes in firstList, and 20k in secondList, it executes under 1 second.

Documentation for [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-7.0), [Linq Except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0)

[DotnetFiddle - reduced numbers to work around memory limitations](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AYZJmR)

```
// Classes used in test: 

public interface IOrderNumber
{
    string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Poco: IOrderNumber
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Podo: IOrderNumber
{
    public string OrderNumber {get;set;}
}

public class DataEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<IOrderNumber>
{
    public bool Equals(IOrderNumber p1, IOrderNumber p2)
    {
        var equal = GetHashCode(p1) == GetHashCode(p2);
        return equal;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IOrderNumber p1)
    {
        if (p1 == null)
            return -1;

        int hCode = p1.OrderNumber.GetHashCode();
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}


... then your code would look like this: 

var firstList = Enumerable.Range(1, 1500000).Select(x => new Poco { OrderNumber = x.ToString() }).ToList();
var secondList = Enumerable.Range(50, 20000).Select(x => new Podo { OrderNumber = x.ToString() }).ToList();
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var result = firstList.Except(secondList, new DataEqualityComparer()).ToList();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Duration: {sw.Elapsed:G}");
```

Comment: This looks great but i think i didn't clarify in the post that the two objects are not of the same type. They are different type objects with one common property. So not sure how this comparer will work to find not matched with two different types.

Comment: Use an interface. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: That would be great thanks

Comment: Hi, What happened to your solution with the interface? It worked. I wanted to accept the answer but its been edited back to the version without the interface.

Comment: Must have had it open in 2 tabs and hit save without looking. Reverted that back to interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more simplified version of your solution, it uses less loops to do the job, but I'm not sure if this will make the process faster, Please let me know if it does

```
notmatched.AddRange(List1.Where(l1=> !list2.Any(l2=> l2.OrderNumber == l1.OrderNumber).Select(l1 => new SomeObj 
    {
    OrderNumber = l1.OrderNumber
    }));
```

Comment: I have tried Any too. Has no improvement.

Answer (score 0):

USE Linq `Except` to compare objects. you must implement an IEquatable Interface for complex objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var first =  new  List<Poco> { new Poco {OrderNumber = "test", Orderid = 1 }, new Poco {OrderNumber = "test", Orderid = 1 }  };
        var second =  new  List<Poco> { new Poco {OrderNumber = "test", Orderid = 1 }, new Poco {OrderNumber = "test", Orderid = 1 }  };
        first.Except(second).Dump();
        second.Except(first).Dump();
        if ( !first.Except(second).Any() && !second.Except(first).Any())
        {
            Console.Write("first and second are equal");
        } else {
            
            Console.Write("equality failed");
        }
        

    }
}

public class Poco : IEquatable<Poco>
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public int Orderid {get; set;}
    public  bool Equals(Poco other)
    {
      if (other == null )
         return false;

      return this.Orderid == other.Orderid &&  this.OrderNumber == other.OrderNumber;
        
   }
   public override bool Equals(Object obj)
   {
      if (obj == null)
         return false;

      Poco poco = obj as Poco;
      if (poco == null)
         return false;
      else
         return Equals(obj);
   }
   
   public override int GetHashCode() => (Orderid, OrderNumber).GetHashCode();
  
}
```